# Passing context to MediaCursorAdapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-context, android-cursoradapter

I created fragment inside activity and fragment needs to call `MediaCursorAdapter` class (which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`) to display songs in listview. But I am having trouble to calling its constructor with context.

> I tried many solutions from stackoverflow like `getActivity`,
>   `getActivity().getBaseContext()`,
>   `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`, `getActivity.getParent()`,
>   `this`, `MainActivity.this` and `MainActivity.class` but nothing is
>   worked.

Here is my line which calls constructor of `MediaCursorAdapter` :

```
mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.songlist_listitem, cursor);
```

This is my `MediaCursorAdapter` class :

```
public class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    String backgroundColor = "white";
    String someOtherBackgroundColor = "#FAFAFA";
    TextView title,name,duration;

    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration, R.id.iv_art});
    }
}
```

> Keep in mind that this all code is inside my `Fragment`.

Comment: define: *but nothing is worked* for example for `getActivity()`

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: When I write `getActivity()` then it gives me error incompatible types.

Comment: Please provide the import section, and a very basic `Fragment` like the BlankFragment generated by Android studio that try to reproduce the problem, that we can reproduce it. Also give the exact error. I get it working fine with `getActivity()`

Comment: Actually error was I have created object of MediaCursorAdapter of another activity and used inside this activity. But now it is solved by getActivity(). Thanks @Geoffrey